# I don't understand how to formulate an if statement with multiple conditions

Tags: python, if-statement

(Sorry if this is an obvious question, I’m new to coding and the textbook is only confusing me)

For an assignment we need to build a generation finder, so if you’re born between 1946–1964 you’re part of the silent generation.

How do you restrict an input to be for a certain range of numbers for each generation?

Ex. 1946-1964 is the silent gen,
1965-1980 are gen x,
1981-1996 are millennials, etc.

I just put:

```
birthYear = input(“What year were you born?: “)
```

And then tried this:

```
If birthYear <= 1964 and >= 1946: 
  print(“You’re a baby boomber!”
```

But it says invalid syntax.

Comment: Note that Python is unusual in that it supports `a <= b <= c` just as you would use in mathematics so you could write `if 1946 <= int(birthYear) <= 1964: print(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
If birthYear <= 1964 and >= 1946: print(“You’re a baby boomber!”
```

Three problems with syntax per se:

1. Should be `if`, not `If`
2. To make a conditional statement about the conjunction of two conditions, you need to say `if EXPRESSION and EXPRESSION`, but `>= 1946` on its own is not a fully-formed expression.   What you mean is `birthYear <= 1964 and birthYear >= 1946`.  It's worth noting, though, that unlike many other languages Python allows you to collapse the conjunction of those two expressions into a single one (without the `and`): `1946 <= birthYear <= 1964` is a valid expression.
3. Your `print` call is missing a closing parenthesis

Once the syntax is fixed, you also have an additional problem of comparing a string `birthYear` against integers.  Convert `birthYear` to an integer with `int()`.

Once the syntax errors and `TypeError` are fixed, you could think about addressing the spelling of "boomer".

Comment: Thanks! Makes much more sense now! And lol, I did think my spelling was off, thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
birthYear = int(input('What year were you born?: '))
if birthYear >= 1946 and birthYear <= 1964:
    print('You\’re a baby boomer!')
```

Comment: Can't directly compare strings to ints.

Comment: Let's turn it into an int, then.